# How to automaticly scale the size of child parents with Css Grid or Flex

Tags: css

So I want to make a structure something similar to this:

```
<div style={{height: "100vh"}}>
  <div style={{height: "auto"}}>{content}</div>
  <div style={{height: "auto"}}>{content}</div>
  <div style={{height: "auto"}}>{content}</div>
</div>
```

For example, I have a 100`%` width and height in `vh` div and have 3 children inside displayed as columns, I want automatically the 3 divs to take size 33.3333% but in a perfect way.

Answer (score 0):

### Grid

You can set the *amount of columns* and the *width* for each one with `grid-template-columns`. In this case we repeat 3 times `1fr`, `1fr` means one fraction of the total, in this case `1fr = 1 / 3`.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  min-width: 100vh;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content</div>
  <div class="child">Content</div>
  <div class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```

### Flex

Here, as you want to force the 1/3 width, make the child items to grow with `flex-grow: 1`. No style is needed to make the columns because it's the default flow for flex.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100vh;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content</div>
  <div class="child">Content</div>
  <div class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```